# MySQL Dropping Tables

Tags: mysql, sql-drop

What syntax for MySQL would I use to drop multiple tables that have a similar pattern to them? Something like:

`` DROP TABLES FROM `Database1` LIKE "SubTable*" ``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. But you can select tables names from `information_schema` database:

```
select table_name
  from information_schema.tables
 where table_schema = 'Database1'
   and table_name like 'SubTable%'
```

And after that iterate the table names in result set and drop them

Comment: How would I iterate that using MySQL?

Comment: It is a shame that this was marked as the correct answer, when both the other answers given actually provide methods for doing exactly as required.

Comment: @Warren Sergent - spakatak.com: there is no "something like" OP required. There is something that takes info from `information_schema` and generates queries, as I stated in my answer. You know, sometimes answers implies you need to think for a second, not just to eat free fish.

Comment: thanks @zerkms i followed your train of thought and simply looped through the table names listed in the information_schema. worked like a charm

Answer (score 4):

Since DROP TABLE was supported by prepared statements, it can be done in this way -

```
SET @tables = NULL;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(table_schema, '.', table_name) INTO @tables FROM information_schema.tables 
  WHERE table_schema = 'Database1' AND table_name LIKE 'SubTable%';

SET @tables = CONCAT('DROP TABLE ', @tables);
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @tables;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

Answer (score 3):

As noted on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758652/mysql-how-to-drop-multiple-tables-using-single-query), the responses given here (Angelin and Devart) won't work in all circumstances without first increasing the limit of group_concat, as per below:

```
SET group_concat_max_len = 1024 * 1024 * 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

> mysql> SELECT CONCAT( "DROP TABLE ", GROUP_CONCAT(TABLE_NAME) ) AS
>   stmt
>
> FROM information_schema.TABLES
>
> WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "your_db_name" AND TABLE_NAME LIKE "ur condition"
>   into outfile '/tmp/a.txt';
>
> mysql> source /tmp/a.txt;