# MySQL: how to drop multiple tables using single query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete, multiple-tables

I want to drop multiple tables with ease without actually listing the table names in the drop query and the tables to be deleted have prefix say 'wp_'

Comment: Similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958424/mysql-question-on-dropping-tables/5430104#5430104

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just sharing one of the solutions:

> mysql> SELECT CONCAT(
>                     "DROP TABLE ",
>                      GROUP_CONCAT(TABLE_NAME)
>              ) AS stmt
>
> FROM information_schema.TABLES
>
> WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "your_db_name" AND TABLE_NAME LIKE "ur
>   condition" into outfile '/tmp/a.txt';
>
> mysql> source /tmp/a.txt;

Answer (score 17):

I've used a query very similar to Angelin's. In case you have more than a few tables, one has to increase the max length of `group_concat`. Otherwise the query will barf on the truncated string that `group_concat` returns.

This is my 10 cents:

```
-- Increase memory to avoid truncating string, adjust according to your needs
SET group_concat_max_len = 1024 * 1024 * 10;
-- Generate drop command and assign to variable
SELECT CONCAT('DROP TABLE ',GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(table_schema,'.',table_name)),';') INTO @dropcmd FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='databasename' AND table_name LIKE 'my_table%';
-- Drop tables
PREPARE str FROM @dropcmd; EXECUTE str; DEALLOCATE PREPARE str;
```

Comment: Thank you for this - without the group_concat_max_len increase, Angelin's answer would never have worked for my scenario.

Answer (score 4):

Simple solution without risk of error:

`mysqldump` create a file that contains `DROP` command like

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `wp_matable`;
```

a '`grep`' with "`DROP TABLE wp_`" give us the commands to execute

so drop is made by theses trhee lines (you can edit drop.sql to check which tables would be dropped before)

```
mysqldump -u user -p database > dump.sql 
grep "DROP TABLE `wp_" dump.sql > drop.sql
mysql -u user -p database < drop.sql
```

Comment: I am not sure if there is an error in your answer but to make the grep command work, I had to write `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` instead of just `DROP TABLE` and I had to escape the backtick with the "\" character. For example:
`grep "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS \\`table_prefix_" dump.sql > drop.sql`.
I did the export simply with `sudo mysqldump > dump.sql` and then logged in as root through Unix socket with `sudo mysql` before selecting the database with `use db_name` and executed the SQL file with `\. drop.sql`.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful with "_", need to be written with "\" before in Mysql like:

```
SELECT CONCAT('DROP TABLE',GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(table_schema,'.',table_name)),';') INTO @dropcmd FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='databasename' AND table_name LIKE '**my\\_table**%';
```

Answer (score 2):

A less complicated solution when a large number of tables are needed to be deleted -

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(table_name SEPARATOR ", ")
    -> AS tables
    -> FROM information_schema.tables
    -> WHERE table_schema = "my_database_name"
    -> AND table_name LIKE "wp_%";
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| tables              
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| wp_t1, wp_t2, wp_t3, wp_t4, wp_t5, wp_t6, wp_t7, wp_t7, wp_ .......... 
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Copy the table names. Then use -

```
DROP TABLE 
    -> wp_t1, wp_t2, wp_t3, wp_t4, wp_t5, wp_t6, wp_t7, wp_t7, wp_ ..........;
```

Answer (score 0):

For the great mysqldump solution it's better to use the option --skip-quote-names

```
mysqldump --skip-quote-names -u user -p database > dump.sql 
grep "DROP TABLE wp_" dump.sql > drop.sql
mysql -u user -p database < drop.sql
```

You get rid of backticks in table names. The grep part won't work in some enviroments with the backticks.

Comment: You can make the backtick work with grep if you escape it with the character "\": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758652/mysql-how-to-drop-multiple-tables-using-single-query#comment108480150_21087169

Answer (score -3):

Go to c:\xampp\mysql\data\your folder

Select multiple tables that you want remove and then press delete button

Thanks

Comment: This makes the assumption that the original poster is using XAMPP and has it installed to that directory.

Answer (score -4):

Dropping single table in mysql:

DROP TABLE TABLE_NAME;